# Looking for a word to describe this

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Hello English StackExchange community,

As I'm attempting to type this out very carefully, I wanted to know of another way to describe the following:

- Large networks that are linked together
- Something that branches off
- Connection between things

The examples I've thought of so far that I've liked are **branch**, **web**, and **circuit**. As all three are large series of things that are connected. For example a branch branches off into more branches, while webs are basically a huge connection of smaller webs, and circuits are connected.

If I've explained well enough, can anybody think of words that can be thought of as something that branches off, connects numerous times, or is a large network of sharing? The reason I need this is for a title for a small applet I'm developing.

Comment: It's called *internet*.

Comment: Large networks that are linked together are “connected networks”.  A network “bridge” connects two networks. A “route” is a path between two routers.

Comment: @Jim I really like "bridge", thank you for that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Large networks that are linked together

In computing, a ***[mesh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mesh)*** usually refers to a network of computers/processors.

> *Computing*: A computer network in which each computer or processor is connected to a number of others, especially so as to form a multidimensional lattice

#### 2. Something that branches off

A ***[node](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/node)*** is a point that has branched off from the root/source and serves as a connecting point.

> *Technical*: A point in a network or diagram at which lines or pathways intersect or branch

#### 3. Connection between things

You can simply refer to this as a ***connection***. Or if you are looking for something else, I suggest ***[link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/link)***

> 1) A relationship between two things or situations, especially where one affects the other
>
> 1.4) *Computing*:  A code or instruction which connects one part of a program or an element in a list to another.

<sub>*Reference*: Oxford Dictionaries Online</sub>

Comment: Many great terms, I never thought of mesh before. Thanks!